# Twitter: Finding number of followers from a Twitter account URL

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter

Is there a way to find the number of followers of a Twitter user just by using the user's Twitter account URL? For example, using a Twitter account URL like `www.twitter.com/abc`, could I find the number of followers that the user corresponding to that account URL currently has?

I have extracted the followers count using `BeautifulSoup` in Python, but is there a non-scraping way to accomplish this? I know that there is an API which finds the followers count using the user id, but couldn't find anything which would help me find the follower count using only the Twitter account URL.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the screen name from the URL, and then use [users/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/lookup), which returns among other things the `follower_count` of the given user.

Comment: This API doesn't seem to work. I'm getting a `{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}` error, even while using the example link provided.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter) is probably worth taking a look at. It also covers authentication, which is the error you are receiving.